# EventTarget in Jmeter

Tags: events, jmeter, target

Posting a request in Jmeter which updates in Database. The response is 200 . But the UI doesnot have the updated values.When seeing the response data i see the Eventtargetvalue as blanks though i pass this on POST
My Post in Body:

```
{
"__EVENTTARGET": "ctl$CttPlHlder1$Submit",
"__EVENTARGUMENT": ,
"__LASTFOCUS": ,
"__VIEWSTATE": "${VIEWSTATEExtractor}",
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "${VIEWSTATEGENERATORExtractor}",
"__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": ,
ctl$CttPlHlder1$txtTaskDate$Date1": "01/20/2017"
}
```

Results:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_ScriptManager1_TSM" id="ctl00_ScriptManager1_TSM" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="8V3AHoa3
```

Comment: please add 1. HTTP request body sampler 2. Corresponding request View Results Tree screenshots.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I do not have access to Post screenshot. In Post request the body is as above mentioned and i have Implementation as : Httpclient4, selected follow redirects,Usekeepalive. I have added authorization manager, cookie manager,HeaderManager

Answer (score 0):

You can try enconding the EventTarget value,

as "__EVENTTARGET": "${__urlencode(ctl$CttPlHlder1$Submit)}"

You should also encode the ViewState value.

Comment: Sorry it doesnot help . It still returns empty value in Results table                                                                                          {
"__EVENTTARGET": "${_urlencode(ctl$CttPlHlder1$Submit)}",
 And the results is <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />